# VB6 To Xls without Excel

Tags: excel, vb6, dao

I have to transfer data from several Flexgrids in different Forms in a VB6 application to .xls files in computers which do not have excel installed. Openoffice, LibreOffice, etc are installed in these PCs.

I developed a common procedure which takes a FlexGrid as a parameter and transfers its data to xls. This procedure uses DAO. As various columns in various FlexGrids contain various data types, in the procedure I am defining the fields as type "dbText".

```
t.Fields.Append t.CreateField(pFlxGrd.TextMatrix(0, j), dbText)
```

Transfer from any grid to xls is working fine. But, a problem is, for every cell that contains data, single quotes are inserted to indicate its data of Text type.

Is there any way to remove or avoid these quotes? As numeric data are to be used for summations, etc, these quotes have to be gotten rid of.

Comment: Try using a numeric data type, such as dbInteger or dbLong?  See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff194420.aspx.

Comment: Using a numeric data type won't help as the procedure is provided a grid as parameter and it simply sends the data of the grid to excel. 
And while creating the fields in tabledef from grid headers, it won't know which is a numeric field and which is not.

Comment: Whether you can do this depends on a few things.  The problem is that the Jet Excel IISAM has to treat each column of the Sheet or Range as a single data type.  Text is normally String, numeric is normally Double, etc.  If the types in an existing Sheet/Range are mixed things can get dicey.  A column might end up as String or as Double depending on what is within the first MaxScanRows (defaults to 8).

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with either the Jet engine, ODBC or accdb.  If you are on a 64 bit system, make sure you run it from the 32-bit cmd prompt in windows\syswow64\cmd.  I don't have VB6 installed so this solution has only been tested in vbscript, which is very similar.  You just have to add the types to the dim statement.

```
dim connExcel, connExcelStr, rsExcel, xlpath

' Get the parameter from the command line
xlpath = WScript.Arguments.Item(0)

' Create the connection
set connExcel = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")

' Setup the connection string
' xlpath = "U:\JetExcel\data.xls"
connExcelStr = "Driver={Microsoft Excel Driver (*.xls)};"
connExcelStr = connExcelStr & "Dbq=" & xlpath & ";"
connExcelStr = connExcelStr & "FIRSTROWHASNAMES=1;"
connExcelStr = connExcelStr & "READONLY=FALSE;"
connExcelStr = connExcelStr & "CREATE_DB=""" & xlpath & """;"

' Create a workbook
WScript.echo connExcelStr
connExcel.Open connExcelStr

' Create a worksheet
sqlQuery = "create table [Sheet1] (ID Number, FirstName Text, LastName Text)"
WScript.echo sqlQuery
set rsExcel = connExcel.Execute(sqlQuery)

' Put data into the worksheet
sqlQuery = "insert into [Sheet1] (ID, FirstName, LastName) values"
sqlQuery = sqlQuery & "(1, 'Humpty', 'Dumpty')"
WScript.echo sqlQuery
set rsExcel = connExcel.Execute(sqlQuery)

' Close workbook
connExcel.Close
set connExcel = nothing
```

If the script is named xxx.vbs, to create an excel sheet

```
cscript xxx.vbs test.xls
```

Answer (score -2):

There is a much faster solution to copy the data from a flexgrid (without the quotation marks) shown in vbForums from a while back - The advantage of this methods is that they work pretty fast, compared to send/bring data cell by cell

```
Private Sub FlexToExcel()
Dim xlObject    As Excel.Application
Dim xlWB        As Excel.Workbook

Set xlObject = New Excel.Application 

'This Adds a new woorkbook, you could open the workbook from file also
Set xlWB = xlObject.Workbooks.Add 

Clipboard.Clear 'Clear the Clipboard
With MSFlexGrid1
    'Select Full Contents (You could also select partial content)
    .Col = 0               'From first column
    .Row = 0               'From first Row (header)
    .ColSel = .Cols - 1    'Select all columns
    .RowSel = .Rows - 1    'Select all rows
    Clipboard.SetText .Clip 'Send to Clipboard
End With

With xlObject.ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet
    .Range("A1").Select 'Select Cell A1 (will paste from here, to different cells)
    .Paste              'Paste clipboard contents
End With

' This makes Excel visible
xlObject.Visible = True
End Sub
```

See [THIS](http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?393082-VB6-Flexgrid-to-Excel-Excel-to-Flexgrid-Fast-copy-using-the-Clipboard) link for more information.

Comment: The question is without excel.

Comment: mmm @Noodles, thank you for the down vote... Excel is not required, only the libraries. If the app is installed all references are made to libraries that is installed with the application!!, no excel application needed. If you read the OP's post properly you will notice that he mentions that the data is send to a .xls file which is, last time I checked an excel document.

Comment: I mean, OP quite clearly stated that Excel isn't installed right there in the first sentence, so...